# I have created a monolithic application using yo jhipster but i am getting error after i have created DTO. I am encountering following error

Tags: jhipster

I Have created an application using `Springboot` but following error occurring when I run mvnw :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheConfiguration' defined in file [F:\Eticketing\target\classes\com\vivek\java\config\CacheConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.vivek.java.config.CacheConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4af1530c]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/jndi/JndiNameException
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:279)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1201)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>               at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>               at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>               at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>               at com.vivek.java.EticketingApp.main(EticketingApp.java:68)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>               at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.vivek.java.config.CacheConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4af1530c]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/jndi/JndiNameException
>               at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271)
>               ... 21 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/jndi/JndiNameException
>               at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>               at org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2554)
>               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>               at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2529)
>               at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516)
>               at org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory.(JCacheRegionFactory.java:45)
>               at com.vivek.java.config.CacheConfiguration.(CacheConfiguration.java:28)
>               at com.vivek.java.config.CacheConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4af1530c.()at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142 23 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiNameException
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>               at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your question and remember to format your code.

Comment: @MohamadShahrestani thank you for your suggestion. can you help me resolve problem?

Comment: some answers here https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. for quotes, errors you just need to use ">" and no need for code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Your cache configuration might be wrong. Go and check your `CacheConfiguration` class. You need to make sure the `CacheConfiguration#cacheManagerCustomizer` method is properly configured for each of your entities.

ie: For a `Foo` entity, you'll need to add the following

```java
cm.createCache(com.test.Foo.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
```

Comment: I have implemented the changes you recommended but still error is occurring again  following is the code in CacheConfiguration.

Comment: // jhipster-needle-ehcache-add-entry
cm.createCache(com.vivek.java.service.dto.LocationDTO.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
cm.createCache(com.vivek.java.service.dto.Department.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
cm.createCache(com.vivek.java.service.dto.TicketStatusDTO.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);

Comment: Your configuration is looking alrgiht, it might be a Hibernate version issue. Try and make sure your Hibernate version is compatible with your Spring version.

Comment: i have recreated entity and it resolved error all are working fine now thank you.